# Use CTE multiple times in a query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have following query

```
with cte as (
select 
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4
from table
)
insert into table (col1,col2) select ct.co1,ct.col2 from cte ct
returning json_build_object(
 'col1',col1,
 'col2',col2,
 'col3',ct.col3,
 'col4',ct.col4
)
```

But its throwing error
**missing FROM-clause entry for table "ct"**

I heard cte can be used multple times in single query, so I believe this could be achievable,

How can I achieve this without using temp table?

Any help, highly appreciating.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with CTE in PostgreSQL but well aware of CTE in SQL. As per my knowledge, Common Table Expressions are temporary in the sense that they only exist during the execution of the query. I think the following part is correct: with cte as (
select 
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4
from table
)
insert into table (col1,col2) select ct.co1,ct.col2 from cte ct

Comment: yes that is correct, issue is with subsequent part while creating the json object

Comment: I think json_build_object should be in the select clause because CTE's scope will lapse at the end of insert into table (col1,col2) select ct.co1,ct.col2 from cte ct

Comment: `insert into table (col1,col2)` <<-- `table` is a bad name for a table. Does it have only two columns? what are their types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the `returning` expression runs in its own context so it does not 'see' `ct`. Try something like this:

```sql
with cte as (
select 
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4
from table_a
) 
insert into table_b (col1, col2) select ct.col1, ct.col2 from cte ct 
returning json_build_object(
 'col1', col1,
 'col2', col2,
 'col3', (select cte.col3 from cte where cte.col1 = table_b.col1 and cte.col2 = table_b.col2),
 'col4', (select cte.col4 from cte where cte.col1 = table_b.col1 and cte.col2 = table_b.col2)
);
```